# OSX Cocoa NSSearchField clear button not responding to click

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, nssearchfield

I place an `NSSearchField` and set its border to `none` and I found that the clear button is not clickable a.k.a. not responding when clicked. If I set the border again it's working fine.

[image]

I've been debugging this for a few hours, and found out that when I set the border to none, the text editor width will expand and shadow (cover) the clear button.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**View hierarchy debug screenshot**

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create an empty cocoa project/app
2. Place an `NSSearchField`
3. Set border to none
4. Run the app, fill the search field and try to click the clear button

Is this a bug? Or is it intended to behave that way?

Note: Newbie in cocoa development

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I faced with this problem and deemed it as a bug in Cocoa. But it is easy to fix in custom control or in a view controller. Just keep text field bordered in interface builder and then kill the border by having new CALayer. For example:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var searchField: NSSearchField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let maskLayer = CALayer()
    searchField.layer = maskLayer
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = searchField.backgroundColor?.CGColor
}
}
```

As you see, I am just restoring control color in new layer not preserving anything else. It is not perfect, but at least gives good start.

Answer (score 1):

[julia_v's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921355/osx-cocoa-nssearchfield-clear-button-not-responding-to-click#38970763) is almost correct. You should also remove searchButtonWidth from rect.origin.x to offset rect back.

And also I've added some more logic to make these "tricks" only, when it needed.

```
override func select(withFrame rect: NSRect, in controlView: NSView, editor textObj: NSText, delegate: Any?, start selStart: Int, length selLength: Int) {

    var newRect = rect

    if !isBordered || isBezeled {
        let cancelButtonWidth = NSWidth(cancelButtonRect(forBounds: rect))
        let searchButtonWidth = NSWidth(searchButtonRect(forBounds: rect))

        newRect.size.width -= (cancelButtonWidth + searchButtonWidth)
        newRect.origin.x += searchButtonWidth
    }
    super.select(withFrame: newRect, in: controlView, editor: textObj, delegate: delegate, start: selStart, length: selLength)
}
```

After creating subclass simply set it to NSSearchFieldCell instance in IB identity inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in NSSearchField, created in code. Solved it by overriding the NSSearchFieldCell method in a subclass:

```
 - (void)selectWithFrame:(NSRect)aRect inView:(NSView *)controlView editor:(NSText *)textObj delegate:(id)anObject start:(NSInteger)selStart length:(NSInteger)selLength
{
    NSRect newRect = aRect;
    newRect.size.width -= (NSWidth([self searchButtonRectForBounds:aRect]) + NSWidth([self cancelButtonRectForBounds:aRect]));
    [super selectWithFrame:newRect inView:controlView editor:textObj delegate:anObject start:selStart length:selLength];
}
```

This method is called after the mouse click on the text area of the field. It also appeared to be a nice place to set the color of the insertion point.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that if Apple fix the bug in selectWithFrame, you'll be passing a smaller rectangle than you should do, and the search field will be too small. Eugene's solution of inserting a layer that hides the border is less likely to have any negative effects when the bug is fixed.